# Unexpected behaviour in LabelEncoder with Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, scikit-learn, preprocessor

I have a pandas Series with a mixture of ints and strings. I wish to treat it all as categorical, and encode the labels. I am using Scikit [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

```
my_series = [1,2,3,'string']
le = prc_scikit.LabelEncoder()
# produces the expected result:
le.fit_transform(small_list)
# raises an error: 
le.fit(small_list)
le.transform(small_list)
```

The error is `ValueError: y contains new labels: ['0' '1' '2']`

I've tried looking at the [source of transform](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c957249/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L130) but cannot figure it out. The workaround of using fit_transform isn't always viable as I want to use this transform on different pandas Series.

Why is this happening, and how can I get around it?

## UPDATE:

I've since realized that I can work around it by fitting the Series as a string:

```
le.fit(small_list.astype(str))
le.transform(small_list)
```

Looked like the labels were strings, but the original Series had Ints.